# Re-executing a script in javascript without making another call to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, vue.js

I am developing a web page in Vue with Laravel as the backend.

I have `page A` which requires `script A` after the page is loaded.
Now, I navigate to `page B` which also requires script A after the page is loaded.

Now `script A` was getting called in a component which is there in both pages.

what script A does is, it looks for a div with ID `some_id` and and append some HTML to it. Now, when I navigate to page B `id` no longer exists on the page but when I come back to the page A that script should be re-executed.

I want to make it work without making another call to the server. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do this ! What you're describing is the essence of spaghetti. In an ideal world, components that are shared between pages shouldn't depend on things in the host page, ids for example. They should be self contained and get called. In this ideal world, scripts don't append HTML. You should try and keep a clear separation between code and markup. In Vue, this means having all your markup in templates.

Then, on the question of avoiding the second network request, is the duplicate request for the script, or is it a request by the script for some data? Can you achieve what you want by setting caching headers on the resource? If not, think about using a containing iframe to preserve some state between page loads.

Comment: Components are completely independent. But this gives a power to the developer to manipulate the component view by injecting another component through a script without making any change in the previous component (something like WordPress). Coming to the second point, it is a duplicate request. Caching will help but what we are developing is a product that updates quite often and it will not be a good user experience to hard reload scripts as soon as we make a release,